# java.security.GeneralSecurityException CryptoCipher when using Apache Crypto Commons

Tags: java, apache, encryption, cryptography

I'm attempting to use the code here for encryption https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-crypto/xref-test/org/apache/commons/crypto/examples/CipherByteArrayExample.html. I copied the code word-for-word and I am not sure why I'm getting this exception as I can't find much on the issue. The only part that I changed was "StandardCharsets.UTF_8" to the String "UTF-8." I am also not interested in using Bouncy Castle or the java JCE as alternatives but am open to other libraries that use AES/DES in CBC/ECB modes (I am aware of the dangers of DES/ECB so no need for the lecture). Thank you.

EDIT:

Stack trace (Note that line 62 of Crypto.java is "CryptoCipher encipher=Utils.getCipherInstance(transform, properties) ):

```
    W/System.err: java.io.IOException: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: CryptoCipher {org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSslCipher} is not available or transformation AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding is not supported.
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.utils.Utils.getCipherInstance(Utils.java:130)
                  at com.example.me.cryptotest.Crypto.test(Crypto.java:62)
                  at com.example.me.cryptotest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    W/System.err: 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)

    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
              Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: CryptoCipher {org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSslCipher} is not available or transformation AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding is not supported.
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.CryptoCipherFactory.getCryptoCipher(CryptoCipherFactory.java:176)

    at org.apache.commons.crypto.utils.Utils.getCipherInstance(Utils.java:128)
                ... 15 more

    W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.utils.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:90)
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.CryptoCipherFactory.getCryptoCipher(CryptoCipherFactory.java:160)
                ... 16 more
              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        W/System.err:     
at     org.apache.commons.crypto.utils.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
                ... 17 more

    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: no native library is found for os.name=Linux and os.arch=x86
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSslCipher.<init>(OpenSslCipher.java:59)
                ... 20 more
              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: no native library is found for os.name=Linux and os.arch=x86
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.NativeCodeLoader.findNativeLibrary(NativeCodeLoader.java:120)
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.NativeCodeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeCodeLoader.java:62)
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.NativeCodeLoader.<clinit>(NativeCodeLoader.java:50)
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.NativeCodeLoader.isNativeCodeLoaded(NativeCodeLoader.java:261)
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.Crypto.isNativeCodeLoaded(Crypto.java:84)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:94)
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSsl.getLoadingFailureReason(OpenSsl.java:114)
                  at org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSslCipher.<init>(OpenSslCipher.java:57)
                ... 20 more
```

Comment: do you have a exception stacktrace to share ? Just to note, I ran the same code in my local and it works like a charm.

Comment: @AmithKumar Hm that's interesting. Yeah it's here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem here:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: no native library is found for os.name=Linux and os.arch=x86
```

Looks like you are not using Oracle JVM. Possible your JVM is reporting different `os.arch` string then standard Oracle JVM, so you need to copy the native library from possibly `linux/i386` to `linux/x86` (wild guess). Fire a google search on this error `no native library is found for os.name=Linux and os.arch=x86`, and playaround with your OS & JVM to help your runtime find the required native library(s).

Update:
If you look at the `README.md' of the project [on github](https://github.com/apache/commons-crypto). You will notice this:

`Portable across various operating systems (currently only Linux/MacOSX/Windows); Apache Commons Crypto loads the library according to your machine environment (it checks system properties, os.name and os.arch).`

And this is the dll structure they have in the code,

[image]

so you can override your System property 'os.arch' to load the native library as per your OS:

```
System.setProperty("os.arch", "@folder")
```

Just for reference, I am running the code in Windows 10 with Oracle JDK8, so my derived path is coming to `/org/apache/commons/crypto/native/Windows/x86_64/commons-crypto.dll`

Hope this will provide you more help in resolving the issue.